# Internal moderators for community chatter groups

Tags: chatter, lightning-community

I have requirement to allow salesforce internal users (i.e.non-community users) to moderate question/answers in community chatter group.

Since, community chatter group is not available in salesforce for internal users, I have created a custom link which redirects users to community page, where they will have to login and then they can moderate.

Is there a way to allow internal users to moderate community chatter group questions without having to re-login to community? Community is not public and it has to be private.